# parallel with copy command is very slow to clone 2 directories

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, multitasking

I am on MacOS Catalina. This command is very slow :

`parallel -j32 cp -rpf {} /Users/henry/ ::: /Volumes/henry/`

The goal is to  clone the `/Volume/henry` to `/Users/henry` directory.

`/Volume/henry` is shared across my network.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong in my command : I have 1.3 TB to clone.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: A few questions: 

1. How slow is "very slow"  - is this a gigabit network? If so, maximum speed will be ~112MB/s, likely less with overhead.

2. 32 parallel threads reading the network drive may be causing I/O issues, you can see if this is happening using something like `htop`

Comment: @Scot from what I have tested, it would take 24 hours or more to copy all files/directories. `htop` doesn't show multiple processes when I launch the above command, surely my command is incorrect, what do you think about this ?

Comment: You likely need an asterisk in there, otherwise parallel won't parallelize the copy. Something like this:
`parallel -j32 cp -rpf {} /Users/henry/ ::: /Volumes/Henry/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should likely be adjusted like this:

`parallel -j32 cp -rpf {} /Users/henry/ ::: /Volumes/henry/*`

Note the asterisk, this will allow `parallel` to parallelize across the folders/files present to be copied within the top level of `/Volumes/henry/`.

With the above command, there will be as many concurrent copies as `/Volumes/henry/*` expands to, which is why the original command (without the asterisk) was slow (it was performing one parallel copy).

However, since you are copying so much information, I'd recommend an alternate approach, and use `rsync` rather than `cp`. `rsync` might be slightly slower, but it verifies that copies complete properly, so would help guarantee that the destination matches the source, and it is resumable in case the process prematurely ends.

Something like this should work:

`parallel -j32 rsync -av {} /Users/henry/ ::: /Volumes/henry/*`

Finally, you may need to play around with the number of maximum threads, 32 might be too high depending on the I/O of your disks on the source and destination, and depending on how many folders/files there are in the folder `/Volumes/henry/`. Since this copy is network bound, 32 threads may not speed the copy up as much as is hoped.

Comment: As the limit here is disk access or network speed I doubt parallel will speed up rsync. Just use the simpler way